# Posts are not refreshing when removing one from the database

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm making a simple blog using a MEAN stack, and I'm running into a simple issue.

Here's the HTML portion I'm using to retrieve all my posts:

`index.html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <h2>
    {{post.title}}
    <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)"class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </h2>
  <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
  <p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>
```

Note that: `<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>` is an icon taken from the [FontAwesome](http://www.fontawesome.io) library

Here's my controller for the angular app:

```
(function () {
  angular
    .module("BlogApp", [])
    .controller("BlogController", BlogController);

    function BlogController($scope, $http) {
      $scope.createPost = createPost;
      $scope.deletePost = deletePost;

      function init() {
        getAllPosts();
      }
      init();

      function deletePost(postId) {
        $http.delete('/api/blogpost/' + postId).then(getAllPosts);
      }
      function getAllPosts() {
        $http.get("/api/blogpost").then(function(posts){
        $scope.posts = posts.data
    });
  }
```

And here's the portion of my server handling the delete request:

```
// deletePost
app.delete('/api/blogpost/:id', deletePost);

function deletePost(req, res) {
  var postId = req.params.id;
  PostModel.remove({_id: postId}).then(
    function() {
      res.sendstatus(200);
    },
    function() {
      res.sendStatus(400);
    }
  );
}
```

When clicking on X icon, the action does hit my controller, reaches the server and manages to delete the post from my database but for some reason, it doesn't update the page automatically with all my posts. I have to refresh it. That's why I thought invoking the function `getAllPosts` in the controller right after hitting the server would update the data. What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.post`?

Comment: Well I added models for title and body as `ng-model="post.title"` so posts is an array of post objects.

I honestly don't know what is written wrong, but I re-wrote the `deletePost` function in the server and now it's working. I think it was an issue with the mongoose promise. I still find that quite confusing to be honest.

Comment: Then you should answer your question accept and close it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing the mongoose promise after removing the specific post and it worked.

```
// deletePost
function deletePost(req, res) {
  var postId = req.params.id;
  PostModel.remove({ _id: postId}).then(function(err){
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    res.send('Post deleted');
  });
}
```

This also seems to work:

```
function deletePost(req, res) {
  var postId = req.params.id;
  PostModel.remove({ _id: postId}).then(
    function(status) {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    }, function() {
      res.send(400);
    }
  );
}
```

Still a bit confused as to how to work with the mongoose promises...